# Sql server deadlock when insert and update in one transaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-sql-database, deadlock

I'm using Azure SQL + Java + Spring Boot 2. Currently I'm trying to understand the reason why deadlocks occur. In a transaction I'm doing insert and later update on the same table but different rows. As far as I understood, SQL Server by default uses `rowlock` and the `read_committed` isolation.

Here is the deadlock details :

```xml
<deadlock>
    <victim-list>
        <victimProcess id="process2b8618644e8"/>
    </victim-list>
    <process-list>
        <process id="process2b8618644e8" taskpriority="0" logused="352"
                 waitresource="KEY: 16:72057594043760640 (5f601e0257f1)" waittime="1321" ownerId="9246067"
                 transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-02-17T13:03:49.683" XDES="0x2b868778458"
                 lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="288932" status="suspended" spid="118" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0"
                 trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2019-02-17T13:03:49.793" lastbatchcompleted="2019-02-17T13:03:49.760"
                 lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.760" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server"
                 hostname="TZ-MacBook-Pro.local" hostpid="0" loginname="master" isolationlevel="read committed (2)"
                 xactid="9246067" currentdb="16" currentdbname="test" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672"
                 clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x431f2517c2d3feb8" queryplanhash="0x3a793ad664472011" line="1"
                       stmtstart="110" stmtend="238"
                       sqlhandle="0x02000000060c530e608cef3b3e4e4712f48c40d2efd9b04d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    unknown
                </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1"
                       sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    unknown
                </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
                (@P0 int,@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 int)update bug set lock=@P0, status=@P1 where
                bug_id=@P2 and lock=@P3
            </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process2b84f702108" taskpriority="0" logused="700"
                 waitresource="KEY: 16:72057594043760640 (185e9bfc7320)" waittime="1287" ownerId="9246090"
                 transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-02-17T13:03:49.727" XDES="0x2b868764458"
                 lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="334812" status="suspended" spid="115" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0"
                 trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2019-02-17T13:03:49.830" lastbatchcompleted="2019-02-17T13:03:49.790"
                 lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.790" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server"
                 hostname="TZ-MacBook-Pro.local" hostpid="0" loginname="master" isolationlevel="read committed (2)"
                 xactid="9246090" currentdb="16" currentdbname="test" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672"
                 clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x431f2517c2d3feb8" queryplanhash="0x3a793ad664472011" line="1"
                       stmtstart="110" stmtend="238"
                       sqlhandle="0x02000000060c530e608cef3b3e4e4712f48c40d2efd9b04d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    unknown
                </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1"
                       sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    unknown
                </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
                (@P0 int,@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 int)update bug set lock=@P0, status=@P1 where
                bug_id=@P2 and lock=@P3
            </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594043760640" dbid="16" objectname="b51ce3c4-02f0-4dfa-89dd-3ab2f45beac7.dbo.bug"
                 indexname="bug_pk" id="lock2b8658c6f00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594043760640">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2b84f702108" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2b8618644e8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594043760640" dbid="16" objectname="b51ce3c4-02f0-4dfa-89dd-3ab2f45beac7.dbo.bug"
                 indexname="bug_pk" id="lock2b856aa7f80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594043760640">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2b8618644e8" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2b84f702108" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Also I'm using a clustered index on my id column and there are no issues with random operations order. Moreover when I only do insert inside transaction everything works fine, without a deadlock.
**If I switch to PostgreSql there are no deadlock issues.**

So why am I getting a deadlock in Azure SQL?

Here is Java source code :

```
    @Transactional
    public void bug() {
        BugEntity bugEntity = bugRepo.findById("1234")
                .orElseGet(() -> createBugEntity());

        if (bugEntity.getStatus().equals("SomeStatus")) {
            bugEntity.setStatus("NewStatus");
            bugRepo.save(bugEntity);
        }

    }

    private BugEntity createBugEntity() {
        BugEntity bugEntity = BugEntity.builder()
                .bugId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .status("SomeStatus")
                .data("SomeData")
                .build();
        return bugRepo.save(bugEntity);
    }
```

Entity class :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity(name = "bug")
@DynamicUpdate
public class BugEntity {

    @Id
    String bugId;
    String status;
    String data;

    LocalDateTime dateTime;

    @Version
    int lock;


}
```

To reproduce the deadlock, I'm using gatling simulation with a few parallel requests.

Comment: What is the data type of the `bug` table `bug_id` and `lock` columns? Your parameter data types are declared as `nvarchar(4000)`, which may result in a scan instead of index seek if the columns are `varchar`. Full scans often lead to deadlocks.

Comment: By mistake I set lock data type as varchar but after change to int deadlock is still there. Bug_id is varchar by design. If it is a source of a deadlock (I'll check it), how can I prevent it without data type changes?

Comment: Spid and kpid are different. The session id and the Windows thread ID are different. The deadlock is not happening in the same transaction.

Comment: Change your app code to pass a `varchar` parameter instead of `nvarchar`. If you don't use `nvarchar` in the database, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821915/sql-server-ignores-index-on-varchar-column-and-does-tablescan-when-queried-from) for a possible solution.

Comment: It usually helps to post the query plans for the two statements that are deadlocking.  You may be doing an index scan on one table taking locks on various rows that later you try to update from another transaction.  It is quite possible to get a deadlock if you have an incompletely tuned OLTP app where one query is doing scans and the other seeks on secondary indexes before doing bookmark lookups into the heap/clustered index.  You don't really have much hope of debugging this until you dig into the SQL layer a bit more.

Comment: @DanGuzman You've made my day! You were right about `varchar` and `nvarchar` issue. After applying the hints from the link that you attached everything works properly. Thank you!

Comment: @Tomo, glad it helped. I detailed the solution with an answer for greater visibility to better help others,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common cause of deadlocks is more data than necessary is touched by queries in need of query and index tuning.

The deadlock trace shows parameters are being passed as `nvarchar(4000)` data types. This may prevent indexes on `varchar` columns from being used efficiently because `nvarchar` has a higher data type precedence than `varchar`. This problem is particularly common when parameter data types are inferred from the application data types because strings are often Unicode, such as in Java and .NET languages, resulting in `nvarchar` parameters regardless of the underlying column data type.

The solution is to use varchar parameters for strings instead of nvarchar unless the underlying column is `nvarchar`. If you don't use `nvarchar` in the database, specify JDBC connection string parameter `sendStringParametersAsUnicode` as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821915/sql-server-ignores-index-on-varchar-column-and-does-tablescan-when-queried-from). Alternatively, change the app code or framework configuration to use a `varchar` parameter type for `varchar` columns.

The best practice is to ensure parameters match the type of the underlying database columns. This will improve performance and concurrency and has other benefits as well.